# How to find average of user-entered floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am messing around with Python and wanted to know how to take the average of a string of floats.

I can do the arithmetic but how would I read a string of floats (it can be any number of floats) a user enters?

For example if a user enters four numbers with spaces:

> 14.5 12.5 22.2 99.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the string up, you use use the `split` method of strings. This will give you a list of strings. You can then use a list comprehension to turn them into floats. Once you have a list of floats, sum them and divide by the list's length to get the mean. `math.fsum` is more accurate than the built-in `sum` for floats, so it's best to use that.

```
import math
# Use input() instead of raw_input() in 3.x
s = raw_input("Input numbers, delimited by spaces: ")
numbers = [float(n) for n in s.split()]
print("Average:", math.fsum(numbers) / len(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
foos = []
foo = raw_input("Enter float:")
while(foo != ''):
    foos += [float(foo)]
    foo = raw_input("Enter float:")

print sum(foos)/len(foos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
string_of_floats = [float(x) for x in input().split()]
average = float(sum(string_of_floats)/len(string_of_floats))
```